# Vuetify v-simple-table loading state

Tags: vue.js, html-table, vuetify.js

I'm trying to show loading state in v-simple-data, but for some reason, it doesn't work, maybe there is another way to do it?

Here is my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-forked-bmobx?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the `dataLoading` variable outside of the timeout. Therefore it is immediately set to `false`. You should move it inside the `timeout` callback.

```
initialize() {
      //you do not need to call the set method; since you are setting a primitive data type; reactivity is detected
      //this.$set(this, "dataLoading", true);
      this.dataLoading = true
      let vm = this;
      setTimeout(() => {
        vm.items = [
          { name: "Art", position: "Manager" },
          { name: "David", position: "Salesman" },
        ];
        // reset the dataLoading only after the data has been loaded.
        vm.dataLoading = false
      }, 1000);
      // this line of code does not wait for the setTimeout to finish. This line of code was resetting your variable without waiting for the timeout to complete; thus you never saw the data loading indicator
      //this.$set(this, "dataLoading", false);
}
```